# NPM install aborts - Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, cpanel

I hope everyone's ok so far. I have a HUGE problem with my production server. I am updating my laravel project on my shared server, which uses CPanel to administrate it. I tried to run several commands such as

- npm install
- npm update
- npm run dev (for mix)
- npm run prod

an none of them have worked so far. All point out to the same issue.

```
glob error [Error: ENOMEM: not enough memory, scandir '/home3/regioye5/.npm/_logs'] {


errno: -12,
  code: 'ENOMEM',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/home3/regioye5/.npm/_logs'
}
[..................] / idealTree:sweetalert2: sill fetch manifest resolve@^1.1.7
<--- Last few GCs --->

[322:0x47cdc20]     2130 ms: Scavenge 43.6 (61.8) -> 39.0 (64.3) MB, 11.2 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 1.000, current mu = 1.000) task
[322:0x47cdc20]     2146 ms: Mark-sweep 39.5 (64.3) -> 13.4 (64.3) MB, 3.3 / 0.0 ms  (+ 1.3 ms in 8 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.3 ms, walltime since start of marking 16 ms) (average mu = 0.997, current mu = 0.997) finalize incremental mar

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: 0xa04200 node::Abort() [npm install]
 2: 0x94e4e9 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [npm install]
 3: 0xb7978e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [npm install]
 4: 0xb79b07 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [npm install]
 5: 0x121bcee v8::internal::Zone::NewExpand(unsigned long) [npm install]
 6: 0x1a7256f v8::internal::compiler::Node::New(v8::internal::Zone*, unsigned int, v8::internal::compiler::Operator const*, int, v8::internal::compiler::Node* const*, bool) [npm install]
 7: 0x1a1ba83 v8::internal::compiler::Graph::NewNode(v8::internal::compiler::Operator const*, int, v8::internal::compiler::Node* const*, bool) [npm install]
 8: 0x1b6b03a  [npm install]
 9: 0x1b6f990 v8::internal::compiler::BytecodeGraphBuilder::VisitJumpLoop() [npm install]
10: 0x1b76331 v8::internal::compiler::BytecodeGraphBuilder::VisitBytecodes() [npm install]
11: 0x1b765c3 v8::internal::compiler::BytecodeGraphBuilder::CreateGraph() [npm install]
12: 0x1b7669e v8::internal::compiler::BuildGraphFromBytecode(v8::internal::compiler::JSHeapBroker*, v8::internal::Zone*, v8::internal::compiler::SharedFunctionInfoRef const&, v8::internal::compiler::FeedbackVectorRef const&, v8::internal::BailoutId, v8::internal::compiler::JSGraph*, v8::internal::compiler::CallFrequency const&, v8::internal::compiler::SourcePositionTable*, int, v8::base::Flags<v8::internal::compiler::BytecodeGraphBuilderFlag, int>, v8::internal::TickCounter*) [npm install]
13: 0x1c0b2e5 v8::internal::compiler::JSInliner::ReduceJSCall(v8::internal::compiler::Node*) [npm install]
14: 0x1c07944 v8::internal::compiler::JSInliningHeuristic::InlineCandidate(v8::internal::compiler::JSInliningHeuristic::Candidate const&, bool) [npm install]
15: 0x1c08094 v8::internal::compiler::JSInliningHeuristic::Finalize() [npm install]
16: 0x1bb5f3e v8::internal::compiler::GraphReducer::ReduceNode(v8::internal::compiler::Node*) [npm install]
17: 0x1a80905 v8::internal::compiler::InliningPhase::Run(v8::internal::compiler::PipelineData*, v8::internal::Zone*) [npm install]
18: 0x1a80e88 v8::internal::compiler::PipelineImpl::CreateGraph() [npm install]
19: 0x1a812a8 v8::internal::compiler::PipelineCompilationJob::PrepareJobImpl(v8::internal::Isolate*) [npm install]
20: 0xc4291e v8::internal::OptimizedCompilationJob::PrepareJob(v8::internal::Isolate*) [npm install]
21: 0xc4402b  [npm install]
22: 0xc451bd v8::internal::Compiler::CompileOptimized(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::ConcurrencyMode) [npm install]
23: 0x1041ce1 v8::internal::Runtime_CompileOptimized_Concurrent(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [npm install]
24: 0x1401219  [npm install]
Aborted
```

Now I can't update anything related to npm (including laravel mix) because of this. Is there a way to give extra memory or to fix this issue with the memory just to run those commands.
this is what I get when I run ulimit -a:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) 800000
scheduling priority             (-e) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 800000
open files                      (-n) 100
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) unlimited
real-time priority              (-r) unlimited
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 20240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 25
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 800000
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

An this is my package.json

```
"private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.3.0",
        "alpinejs": "^2.8.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.18",
        "laravel-mix-merge-manifest": "^2.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "postcss": "^8.2.13",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.1.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "sweetalert2": "^10.16.6"
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to increase memory limit , for example
`export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096`

Comment: I tried, but nothing seems to change. It remains out of memory